I tried to transfer funds from my trust wallet and am being told the transfer didn’t go through because of a bad withdrawal channel . I s this possibl
I tried to transfer funds Out of my trust, wallet to my bank account and him being told the transfer did not go through because of a hacked or broken withdrawal channel. Is this possible they are saying I need to pay 5% of the amount to fix it

The DAAP platform told me I needed to send 28 k within 48 hours or I may lose the funds and not be able to make any further withdrawals. I am not sure if this is a scam

I recommend to learn more about how blockchain works. Transactions require a fee to be paid, but it is usually a fixed amount independent of the value transferred. It is usually paid on the chain native currency (there a few exceptions).  As stated in the question it looks like a common scam. You got a virtual currency/NFT for free and it is required to pay certain amount to withdraw. It is the modern equivalent of free candy.
